# iOS Hockey show update prompt again and again

Tags: ios, hockeyapp

I am using hockey to distribute enterprise applications. For one user, he received prompt to update and he did that. But, when he open app again after update is completed, he still see update prompt again. It look like update is not finished. How shall I debug or solve that case?

Comment: I recommend you contact the HockeyApp support through the appropriate channels. This is a very customer specific problem that's not likely to be solved through Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes. I have contact and they can't simulate the issue. I worry that one of my code affect hockey and wondering other people might have same issue.

Comment: Then you should provide more details to the support or maybe try to reproduce it in a sample project that you can share with them

Comment: I suggest that the user could uninstall the app and reinstall the latest version.